# UIActionSheet crash when selecting item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIView` which I am adding to my `UIViewController` programatically.  This view contains some buttons, one of which opens a `UIActionSheet`.

When I tap any one of the `UIActionSheet` options, the app immediately crashes before the delegate is called.

I'm assuming this is a memory issue, but I think I have covered all the corners.

- The custom `UIView` is a strong property on the parent view controller.
- The action sheet is being shown from the parent view controller's tab bar.
- The action sheet delegate is the `UIView` and the delegate method is implemented correctly.

The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  ([ContactOptionView actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance)

Any help, much appreciated.

The action sheet is created with this code, where the CDField object is a core data NSManagedObject:

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
sheet.title = title;
for (CDField *field in fields) {
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:field.value];
}
sheet.cancelButtonIndex = [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
sheet.delegate = self;
[sheet showFromTabBar:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Comment: Could you show the error message?

Comment: Please show some code too. Thanks.

Comment: @Larme - question updated.

Comment: Have you NSLog'ed all of your "field.value" values to ensure that they are valid?

Comment: Since it crash after you click on a button, I think that the code of your UIActionSheet Delegate method could be useful. Also, try to enable NSZombies to know more about the crash. Try also to determine what line causes the crash.

Comment: @bachonk - All field values are valid.

Comment: @Larme - Zombies are now switched on and the error I'm getting is: -[ContactOptionView actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: @Larme - OK!  I got it!  Thanks so much!  I was setting my ContactOptionView to nil when the user long press gesture recogniser ended - which happens when the user lifts their finger to then tap the action sheet.  Thanks so much for your help! You fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the ActionSheet as strong class property instead of the local declaration may fix this issue due to extending its time to live.

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;

@end    
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize actionSheet = _actionSheet;
- (UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    if (!_actionSheet) {
        _actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title 
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"do something", nil), nil];
    }
    return _actionSheet;
}
```

hth,
Peter

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I tried that and it unfortunately didn't make any difference.

Comment: the error message tells something about accessing an object, that has been removed. What is inside your delegate methods? have you tried to comment out everything in the delegate methods, so that you just do an NSLog("bla") statement or debugging with a breakpoint?

Comment: None of the delegate methods get called.

Comment: hmmm... i have updated my answer with some sample code. that code is indeed working for me...

Comment: Peter - I solved the problem now. I was deallocating the UIView when the user lifted their finger from the screen (meaning that the action sheet's delegate no longer existed).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with the help of @Larme.  The UIView which I was adding to my view controller was being created on a long press gesture, and when the long press gesture ended the view was being deallocated.  When displaying the action sheet, the user must take their finger off the screen to tap the chosen option, and it was at this point that the action sheet's delegate (the view) was being deallocated.